# Basis for co-countable topology

Tags: general-topology

What is the basis set that generate co-countable topology on real line?
I know that Topology it self a basis. But can i form a basis which is subset of T and makes that as co countable topology?

Comment: I may be mistaken but isn't the (uncountable) set $(\mathbb R \setminus \{x_0 \} )_{x_0 \in \mathbb R}$ such a basis?

Comment: That is a subbase for the cofinite topology.